# Where did Unity3D just install?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, uninstall

I downloaded the Linux beta `.deb` package of Unity3D from the official place with the official links. (I'm too lazy to recover the link and include it; it doesn't *really* matter anyways.)

I ran `sudo dpkg -i unity3d.deb`, and the package installed.

I don't want Unity, and now neither `which` nor `sudo locate unity3d` return anything.

I'm aware U3D is closed source; are its installation files masked or hidden? I can't find anything about this.

---

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove unity3d
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove unity3d which isn't installed
```

Comment: Is this [the link](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/)? Or there's a newer release?

Comment: @Alex that is **the link**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the package either isn't installed, or it's name is different than you expect. You can use `--info` option on `.deb` file to check proper name:

```
dpkg --info unity3d.deb
```

If you're concerned about contents and their locations, OSS or not, typically you can check them with `--contents` option:

```
dpkg --contents unity3d.deb
```

Unity package doesn't need source code to work, so there's no reason to hide anything.

Last thing: your `which` isn't working, because it can't find the *exact* filename you provide it in your `PATH`; it isn't a tool like `locate`, which does partial matches. As for `locate` itself - it has a database for lookups, and this database requires updates. There might be a chance that you didn't force update, and it didn't happen anywhere after your installation spontaneously - you can run it with `sudo updatedb`, or `sudo -b updatedb` if you prefer running it in the background.